# Signature difference between lambda with/without captured variable?

Tags: lambda, c++11

I'm playing around with C++11 right now and found the following problem with using a lambda as callback to sqlite. When capturing a vector variable inside the lambda, I get an error saying that the signatures don't match. Without using that variable in the lambda (`[]` instead of `[&ret]`, and not using `ret` inside), it works fine.

```
vector<SomeClass> ret;
char *err = nullptr;
int res = sqlite3_exec(db,
                       "some sql query, doesn't matter",
                       [&ret](void *unused, int argc, char **argv, char **columnName) -> int
                       {
                           ret.push_back(SomeClass());
                           return 0;
                       },
                       nullptr,
                       &err);
```

This is the error I get:

```
cannot convert 'TestClass::testMethod()::<lambda(void*, int, char**, char**)>' to 'int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**)' for argument '3' to 'int sqlite3_exec(sqlite3*, const char*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, char**)'
```

GCC version is "gcc (XvidVideo.RU - GCC 4.6.1 i686-pc-mingw32) 4.6.1 20110625 (prerelease)" on Windows.

Why does this make a difference?

Comment: I'm trying the same thing with the visual studio 2010 compiler and it doesn't like either form of the lambda... Does anyone know if this is a known bug in the VS2010 impl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only captureless lambdas can be converted to pointers to function, and, based on the compiler diagnostic, your `sqlite3_exec` expects such a pointer, `int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**)`.

To quote §5.1.2[expr.prim.lambda]/6

> The closure type for a lambda-expression with no lambda-capture has a public non-virtual non-explicit const conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s function call operator.

Comment: Makes sense. Just wanted to know if I can solve this with captured variables in any way. (In this special case I can of course use sqlite's callback variable for my purposes.)

Comment: @AndiDog I am guessing you'd have to go the way of so many C++ callbacks for C libraries: a non-member or static member function that figures out what to really call based on some `void*`.

Comment: Yes, `sqlite3_exec` allows me to pass a `void*` to the callback, I just naively thought this could be done easier with C++11.

Answer (score 2):

what about using the 1st argument for callback?

```
vector<SomeClass> ret;
char *err = nullptr;
int res = sqlite3_exec(db,
                       "some sql query, doesn't matter",
                       [](void *ctx, int argc, char **argv, char **columnName) -> int
                       {
                           static_cast<vector<SomeClass>*>(ctx)->push_back(SomeClass());
                           return 0;
                       },
                       &ret,
                       &err);
```