# How to "cast" a two-argument function into a one-argument function?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, lambda, function-binding

In matlab, one can write:

```
S = @(x,y) x^2+y^2-1
G = @(x) S(x,1);
```

If I have a function expecting a one-argument function, I can do the above.  How can I do this in c/c++?

I have a library function (from the CGAL library) that expects as an argument a function that itself has only one argument.  Ideally, I have a class (`SphericalHarmonics`) and I would like to have a member function which takes the one argument.  So I have:

```
FT SphericalHarmonics::distFunction(Point_3 p)
```

(note that `FT` is a type similar to `double`) but of course when I try

```
SphericalHarmonics *sh = new SphericalHarmonics(1);
Surface_3 surface(sh->distFunction, Sphere(ORIGIN,2.));
```

`this` is also treated as an argument, my `distFunction` function is a two-argument function, and an error is thrown.

Note that this can be solved with global variables, i.e.

```
SphericalHarmonics *sh;
FT dist_function(Point_3 p) {
    return sh->distFunction(p);
}

main() {
    sh = new SphericalHarmonics(1);
    Surface_3 surface(dist_function);
}
```

However, this is really non-ideal.  I'd like a way to do this without global variables, as it would be far better to be able to have a class function that easily integrates with the CGAL library.

Thanks in advance!

**[UPDATED]**

@Andy-Prowl: I have tried your `std::bind` and `lambda` solutions, but still seem to be running into errors with regards to the number of arguments.

When, in `main`, I use the code:

```
SphericalHarmonics *sh = new SphericalHarmonics(cInit, numL, symm);
auto fxn = std::bind(&SphericalHarmonics::distFunction, sh, std::placeholders::_1);
Surface_3 surface(fxn, Sphere_3(ORIGIN,2.));
```

I get the errors:

```
~/lib/basisfunctions/SphericalHarmonics2/mesh_an_implicit_function.cpp:62:48: 
error: no matching function for call to     
‘CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<CGAL::Robust_circumcenter_traits_3<CGAL::Epick>, 
double (*)
(CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>)>::Implicit_surface_3(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn
<double (SphericalHarmonics::*)(CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>)>
(SphericalHarmonics*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>&, Sphere_3)’
```

and

```
~/CGAL-4.1/include/CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h:50:5: note:   no known conversion 
for argument 1 from ‘std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<double (SphericalHarmonics::*)
(CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>)>(SphericalHarmonics*, std::_Placeholder<1>)>’ to 
‘CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<CGAL::Robust_circumcenter_traits_3<CGAL::Epick>, 
double (*)(CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>)>::Function 
{aka double (*)(CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>)}’
```

and

```
~/CGAL-4.1/include/CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h:34:9: note:   
candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

**[UPDATED]**

It is now clear to me that I need a function which can be converted to a function pointer (i.e. `surface` required a function pointer argument).  This rules out the `std::bind` option.  Moreover, it appears that a lambda cannot be converted to a function pointer if it captures variables ([capture-less vs. capturing lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210818/signature-difference-between-lambda-with-without-captured-variable)).  So I think Andy-Prowl's answer below is in general the correct answer to this question, although I'll need to find a different work-around.

Comment: (I haven't really read the question) bind or a lambda?

Comment: The tags are misleading, should contain matlab/lambda

Comment: Are any of these solutions actually working? Is it not possible to use bind to stand in for the function pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

In case your member function does not to implicitly work on an instance of your class (and therefore does not need to receive a `this` pointer), you can make it `static`:

```
class SphericalHarmonics
{
    ...
    static double distFunction(Point p);
    ...
};

double SphericalHarmonics::distFunction(Point p)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, your function will effectively have a single argument:

```
surface(SphericalHarmonics::distFunction);
```

**OPTION 2:**

Otherwise, you may use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to curry the member function `distFunction` and fix its first, implicit argument (if you are not working with a C++11 compiler, you can use the equivalent `boost::bind()` from the [Boost.Bind](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Flibs%2Fbind%2Fbind.html&ei=E6MuUbqyFsXL4ATrkYHgCw&usg=AFQjCNHjl7JJUv8uYmYkmD9tz86d7AlcXA&sig2=SwxVew1y8gKMfabL5HI1vA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE) library):

```
#include <functional>

SphericalHarmonics *sh = new SphericalHarmonics(1);
auto fxn = std::bind(&SphericalHarmonics::distFunction, sh, _1);
surface(fxn);
```

**OPTION 3:**

Alternatively, in C++11, a lambda could do the job:

```
SphericalHarmonics *sh = new SphericalHarmonics(1);
auto fxn = [=] (double d) { return sh->distFunction(d); }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm sure this is correct so I've already check-marked it.  Option 1 is not an option (I want to work on specific class instances).  When I try either Option 2 or 3 I get the errors `error: 'fxn' does not name a type` and `error: 'fxn' was not declared in this scope.  I've tried both `std::bind` and `boost::bind` (includind `<functional>` and `<boost/bind.hpp>`) and I get the same error.  Using gcc version 4.6.3 on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @OwenM: Are you using a C++11 compiler with the `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` command-line option? The `auto` keyword requires C++11. I also suggest you to upgrade to GCC 4.7.2, the version you are using is quite old. There is also [this website](http://www.liveworkspace.org) where you can compile your code with different compilers.

Comment: Yep, gcc 4.7.2 with -std=c++11 fixed this issue!

Comment: @OwenM: OK, that's good to hear, but why did you un-accept this answer?

Comment: Sorry, see above.  I'm still having difficulties getting compilation, and it seems to be a real issue (i.e. not a wrong-compiler type of issue).  Should I have provided my issues in a direct comment to you, as opposed to editing my original post?  I'm still figuring out the protocols here...

Comment: @OwenM: OK, but that's not the way of notifying this. I don't receive a notification if you address me that way in the question's text, so I totally missed it.

Comment: @OwenM: Also, the fact that you have *further* issues with a *different* code is no reason for un-accepting an answer. Rather, you should ask another one. I'm sure you're using `bind` the wrong way, but I need to see more code to help. Please, re-accept this answer, make a new question out of the new code, where you show all the necessary definitions, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Understood, thanks (with regards to the notifications).  For my original code your answer doesn't work.  I'll be happy to remove my new examples (which simply replaces my class function with a simple stand-alone function) and show the error messages with the code examples you provided, if you'd prefer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25306/discussion-between-owenm-and-andy-prowl)

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html) :

```
#include <functional>   

SphericalHarmonics *sh = new SphericalHarmonics(1);
surface(std::bind(&SphericalHarmonics::distFunction, sh, _1));
```

Comment: Do you mean sh instead of this?

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of dealing with CGAL's templated `Surface_3` class. You're probably using something like this (from their example) to define `Surface_3` type:

```
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3 Tr;
// c2t3
typedef CGAL::Complex_2_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C2t3;
typedef Tr::Geom_traits GT;
typedef GT::Sphere_3 Sphere_3;
typedef GT::Point_3 Point_3;
typedef GT::FT FT;
typedef FT (*Function)(Point_3);
typedef CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<GT, Function> Surface_3;
```

This is *misleading* because it makes it seem like CGAL's isosurface classes can only deal with function pointers (as opposed to `std::function` etc.). But the problem is only that we've *just defined it that way*. Simply define `Surface_3` to use `std::function<FT (Point_3)>` as its template argument and the `std::bind` and lambdas from [Andy Prowl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125180/148668) will work just fine:

```
...
typedef std::function<FT (Point_3)> Function;
typedef CGAL::Implicit_surface_3<GT, Function> Surface_3;
```